# Deserialize XML Elements to Java Map

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I am trying to deserialize an XML file to Java objects using simpleXML. Everything was working fine until I had to use an ElementMap.
This is part of my XML file:

```
<piece composer="Me" date="Yesterday" title="Important work">
    <editions>
        <edition name="My Name" date="2015" description="A single page">
            <pages>
                <page fileName="page01.jpg" />
            </pages>
        </edition>
        <edition name="My Name again" date="2015" description="Another single page">
            <pages>
                <page fileName="page01.jpg" />
            </pages>
        </edition>
    </editions>
    <layers>
        <layer name="Annotations" color="#FF0000" description="Empty" id="anno" />
        <layer name="Information" color="#00FF00" description="Empty" id="info" />
    </layers>
</piece>
```

The corresponding Java Class looks like this:

```
@Root
public class Piece {
    @Attribute
    private String composer;
    @Attribute
    private String title;
    @Attribute
    private String date;

    @ElementList
    private List<Edition> editions;

    @ElementMap(key = "id", attribute = true) // Relevant
    private Map<String, Layer> layers;        // Lines

    public static Piece loadFromAsset(Context context, String fileName) throws Exception {
        Serializer serial = new Persister();
        return serial.read(Piece.class, context.getResources().getAssets().open(fileName));
    }
}
```

And finally the Layer Class:

```
public class Layer {
    @Attribute
    private String id;
    @Attribute
    private String name;
    @Attribute
    private String description;
    @Attribute
    private String color;
}
```

After loading the XML file the Map contains both keys, but they both point to `null` instead of actual Layer Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not SimpleFrawmerow user so I am not guarantee it will work but you should probably specify more attirbutes of ElementMap mappings:

```
@ElementMap(key = "id", attribute = true, keyType=String.class
            ,valueType=Layer.class)
```

If it does not help you have to handle list to map conversion yourself. The problem is that your xml holds actually a list of Layer elements instead of the map (there are no pairs of key /value elements).

You can add to your Piece class extra field to store that list and have the map field constructed using it:

```
class Piece {
    ...
   @ElementList //only for solution B, for a do not use this annotation
   List<Layer> layers;

    @Transient //importatnt as it does not go into xml directly
    private Map<String, Layer> layersMap;        
}
```

now there are two approaches:

A) use getters and setters for layers list, and inside the methods construct the list map content as needed:

```
   @ElementList
   public void setLayers(Collection<Layer> layers) {
      layersMap = new HashMap<>();
      for (Layer l : layers) layersMap.put(l.getId(),l);
   }        

   @ElementList
   public Collection<Layer> getLayers() {
      return layersMap.values();
   }
```

B) use the serialization life cycle mechanism (Persist and Commit annotations). In one method called before the serialization you create the list content using the map in the other you populate the map using the list values. I personally prefer it to getters/setters as you can hide the 'layers' element.

```
class Piece {
....
@Commit
public void prepareMap() {
    layersMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Layer l : layers) layersMap.put(l.getId(),l);
}

@Persist
public void prepareList() {
    layers = new ArrayList<>();
    layers.addAll(layersMap.values());
} 
}
```

Finally you can use the Converter to control the process completely but I believe the above are easier and less verbose.

Comment: Thank you very much! I acutally ended up using your method A with pretty much the exact same syntax.
The other solutions are not less working, but simple is beautiful. ;-)